# How to locate module inside PyCharm?

Tags: python, module, navigation, pycharm

I am a beginner in python 3. I want to locate where the `time` module is in PyCharm to study it's aspects/functions further. I can't seem to find it in the library. Can someone show me an example on how to find it ?

I know there are commands to find files, but I am not advanced enough to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find `time` module, easiest way is to `import time` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd>. It will open that file for you. Then you can use *Select Opened File* button on the left inside *Project* that will show you where current opened file is located at.

Here is example (*minor bug showing StackOverflow while recording, ignore that*):
[image: Find time module]

This is also applicable to any import you have and PyCharm can find.

Comment: Thank you so much Dinko Pehar that really helped!

Comment: No problem @MustafaAbdulhussein . If this answer solved you problem, please consider accepting it by click check mark next to answer. It helps to build positive community and it can help someone having same problem as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misconception - the `time` module is part of your Python installation, which PyCharm makes use of when you run files. Depending on your setup, you may be able to view the Python files under "external libraries" in your project viewer, but you could also view them from your file system, wherever Python is installed.